# Guzzle - вход на сайт

Tags: php, guzzle

Пытаюсь сделать вход в личный кабинет beeline kz, вообще застрял. Почему-то не идут редиректы, хотя они вроде как разрешены.

```
$client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://my.beeline.kz/',
        'cookie' => true,
        'verify' => false,
        'allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]
    ]);

    $cookieJar = new CookieJar();

    $response = $client->get('login.xhtml', [
        'cookie' => true,
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    ]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'login.xhtml', [
            'form_params' => [
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm' => 'loginFormB2C:loginForm',
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm:login' => $login,
                'hiddenpwd' => $password,
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm:passwordPwd' => '',
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm:password' => $password,
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm:j_idt74_input' => 'on',
                'loginFormB2C:loginForm:loginButton ' => '',
                'javax.faces.ViewState' => 'stateless'
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xm…ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language' => 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Content-Length' => '315',
                'Host' => 'my.beeline.kz',
                'Origin' => 'https://my.beeline.kz',
                'Referer' => 'https://my.beeline.kz/login.xhtml',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
            ],
            'cookies' => $cookieJar,
            //'debug' => true,
            'on_stats'=>function (TransferStats $stats){
                echo $stats->getEffectiveUri()."\n";
            },
        ]);

        $headersRedirect = $response->getHeader(RedirectMiddleware::HISTORY_HEADER);
        dd($headersRedirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```php
'allow_redirects' =>  true
```